# "when" is not a function nodejs error while using cucumber

Tags: node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var browser = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

const {Then, When} = require('cucumber');
const assert = require('assert');

 When(/^I search Google for "([^"]*)"$/, (text) =>{

      browser.get('http://www.google.com');
}) ;

When(/^I enter "([^"]*)" in input$/, function(expression){

       browser.get('http://www.google.com');
}) ;
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's easier to understand.  Also, please include the error and related information in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring When and Then into a single const which won't work. To overcome this issue, you can import it using import {When, Then} from 'cucumber';